# Javascript Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of text that I am trying to remove from a textarea in javascript.  The text that I am trying to remove is in the following format:

Category:Attribute

Color:Green <- Example!

```
var catTitle = 'color';
var regexp = new RegExp(catTitle + '\:[.]*$', "g")
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(regexp, "");
```

Since the attribute can be any length, I need my regular expression to go forward until the new line.  I thought that [.]*$ would be acceptable to match any characters up to a new line; however, it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` *inside* a character class (`[]`) matches itself -- it is no longer a wildcard. Also, regular expressions are *case sensitive* unless told otherwise ("i" flag) and `:` (in that context) is not special so it does not need to be escaped.

`[a-z]` or `\w` might be good to use to match the Attribute, depending.

It might then go like:

```
var catTitle = "color"
var re = new RegExp(catTitle + ':[a-z]+$', "gi")
re.test("Color:Green") // true
re.test("color:Red")   // true
re.test("color: Red")  // false, put perhaps this should be accepted?
re.test("color:")      // false
re.test("foo:bar")     // false
```

I also changed the qualifier from `*` to `+` -- note the case of "color:" and how it's rejected. This will also reject colors in non-English alphabets.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response - I will mark it as the answer.  Once the 10 minutes is up.

Comment: Wait a few hours (or more), then make a choice :)

Answer (score 0):

Or, since you may have more lines:

```
var catTitle = 'Color';
var regexp = new RegExp(catTitle + ':.*', "g")
alert("skzxjclzxkc\nsasxasxColor:Red\nasdasdasd".replace(regexp, ""));
```